# Separation of benzoic acid and naphthalene from its mixture

Tags: organic-chemistry, separation-techniques, sublimation

**The best method for the separation of naphthalene and benzoic acid from their mixture ?**
a)chromatography b)crystallization
c)distillation.  d)sublimation

many sources says answer is crystallization and others say sublimation....I am confused rn...which is the correct one...

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: There is no best method and there are multiple best methods.  As being the best one depends on the applied criteria and their weight. The criteria may be cost, time, manual effort, complexity of the process, equipment demand,  efficiency of separation, risk of contamination or decomposition and some more. The weights depend on priorities. // Crystalization and sublimation are the  candidates.

Comment: The answer is e), none of the above. Ether extraction of neutral naphthalene from the sodium salt of benzoic acid in aq. NaOH. Acidify, extract benzoic acid.

Answer (score 3):

Chromatography is good for separating very small amounts of chemicals but is not, in general, good for separating large (macroscopic) amounts of substances.

Both naphthalene and benzoic acid are solids at room temperature so distillation doesn't seem very viable.

Recrystallization might work, but you'd need to have only one compound crystallize. Separating based on crystal structure isn't viable. However you might be able to keep benzoic acid in a basic solution while crystallizing naphthalene.

Naphthalene is used in moth balls and so has an appreciable vapor pressure. Thus sublimation would be the best choice from those given.

However if I had to do this, I'd try some sort of two phase separation in a sepatory funnel. I'd extract the benzoic acid into a basic solution, then acidify the basic solution to get benzoic acid again. Evaporate the solvent from the naphthalene to recover it.

Benzoic acid and naphthalene are such different chemicals that it is hard to conceive how you'd end up with a mixture of the two. The point of using a two phase liquid extraction would be to increase the purity of the benzoic acid. I'd worry that benzoic acid might be coating some naphthalene particles preventing those naphthalene particles from subliming.

In either case, a simple melting point test of both after separation would give a good indication of their individual purity.